# Unbind all event handlers, do something and then bind again with jquery

Tags: jquery, bind, unbind

I tried to store all event handler of an element, then unbind them, then do something and then bind again, but aparently the variable with the handlers gets modified to an empty object when i unbind the handlers

```
  var events = $._data(this.$element.get(0), 'events');
  console.log(events);    //here the variable events contains an object with the handlers
  this.$element.unbind();
  console.log(events);   //here the variable events contains an empty object

  //function to bind again the handlers
  $.each(events, function() {
    // iterate registered handler of original
    $.each(this, function() {
      $('#target').bind(this.type, this.handler);
    });
  });
```

Comment: You need to make a copy of the `events` object. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/most-elegant-way-to-clone-a-javascript-object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`extend`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) in deep mode to copy data in `events`:

```
var events = $._data(this.$element.get(0), 'events'),
    eventsCopy = $.extend(true, {}, events);
this.$element.unbind();
$.each(eventsCopy, function() {
    $.each(this, function() {
        $('#target').bind(this.type, this.handler);
    });
});
```